# Not expired Laravel passport token

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport, laravel-authentication

I'm developing standard Laravel REST API. I'm following the [Laravel 5.4 API Authentication (Passport) Documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#token-lifetimes)

What I need is, User should log in through API and get access token which will not be expired.

`oauth_access_tokens` table has the `expires_at` column. The default value is one year. I changed the expires_at date to yesterday. but still, it works. I search about [Laravel Passport token lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609436/laravel-passport-token-lifetime#targetText=The%20createToken()%20method%20creates,Passport%3A%3ArefreshTokensExpireIn()%20methods.)
. Someone says **the expiration date is not checked at any request.**

Is it true? If it is true, what is the purpose of `expires_at` column? Could anyone explain me please?

Thank You. (`"laravel/passport": "~4.0"`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the expires_at column is not checked by the api middleware. The purpose of the table is to check the existence of the token.